# Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Tags: string, flutter, types, runtime-error

I have the following flutter code in my registration_controller.dart

```
 saveBankDetailsUser(
      {required String accountName,
      required String accountNumber,
      required String bankName,
      required String bankCode}) async {
    ProgressDialogHelper().showProgressDialog(Get.context!, "Processing...");
    try {
      BvnResponse? details = await cachedData.getBvnRequestDetails();
      String bvnRef = details!.data.reference!;
      debugPrint("bvnRef in function");
      await DioServices().confirmBVN(reference: bvnRef).then((value) async {
        //debugPrint(value.data);
        debugPrint("b4 value data");
        print(value.data.runtimeType);
        print(value.runtimeType);
        debugPrint("after runtimeType");


        debugPrint("after jsonDecode value data");
        debugPrint(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value.data)));
        debugPrint("after print jsonDecode of value data");


        //final response = BvnConsent.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value.data)));
        debugPrint("v data");
        //String userPhone = value.data.bvnData.phoneNumber1;
        //String userPhone = response[data][phoneNumber1];
        //debugPrint("userPhone");
        String dob = value.data.bvnData.dateOfBirth;
        //String dob = response[data[dateOfBirth]];
        debugPrint(dob);
        //debugPrint(accountNumber);

        await DioServices()
            .verifyBankDetails(
          accountNumber: accountNumber,
          bankCode: bankCode,
        )
            .then((value) async {
          ;
          accountName = value.data!.accountName!;

          debugPrint("accountName");
          await DioServices()
              .saveVerifiedBankDetails(
                  accountName: accountName,
                  accountNumber: accountNumber,
                  bankName: bankName,
                  bankCode: bankCode,
                  bvn: savedBvn,
                  userPhone: userPhone,
                  dob: dob)
              .then((value) async {
            await updateOnBoardingStage(onBoardStage: "upload_profile_Photo")
                .then((value) async {
              UserPersonalData? resp = await cachedData.getUserPersonalData();
              ProgressDialogHelper().hideProgressDialog(Get.context!);
              // Get.to(() => AddCardScreen());
              Get.offAll(() => CameraApp(id: resp!.user.id.toString()));
              //Get.off(() => CameraApp(id: DateTime.now().toString()));
              // Get.offAll(() => const CreatePin());
            });
          });
        });
      });
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      final errorMessage = DioException.fromDioError(err).toString();
      ProgressDialogHelper().hideProgressDialog(Get.context!);
      FlushBarHelper(Get.context!)
          .showFlushBar(err.response?.data["message"] ?? errorMessage);
      throw errorMessage;
    } catch (err) {
      ProgressDialogHelper().hideProgressDialog(Get.context!);
      FlushBarHelper(Get.context!).showFlushBar(err.toString());
      throw err.toString();
    }
  }
```

It returns error at the point at which I call

`final response = BvnConsent.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value.data)));`

Error returned is - E/flutter (  638): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
E/flutter (  638): #0      RegistrationController.saveBankDetailsUser (package:phincash/src/auth/registration/controller/registration_controller.dart:544:7)

Also here is the model for  Bvnconsent

```
import 'dart:convert';

BvnConsent bvnConsentFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> str) =>
    BvnConsent.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(str)));

String bvnConsentToJson(BvnConsent data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class BvnConsent {
    BvnConsent({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });
  late final String status;
  late final String message;
  late final Data data;

  BvnConsent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> _json){
    status = _json['status'];
    message = _json['message'];
    data = Data.fromJson(_json['data']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['status'] = status;
    _data['message'] = message;
    _data['data'] = data.toJson();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.status,
    required this.reference,
     this.callbackUrl,
    required this.bvnData,
    required this.createdAt,
  });
  late final String firstName;
  late final String lastName;
  late final String status;
  late final String reference;
  late final dynamic callbackUrl;
  late final BvnData bvnData;
  late final String createdAt;
  
  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> _json){
    firstName = _json['first_name'];
    lastName = _json['last_name'];
    status = _json['status'];
    reference = _json['reference'];
    callbackUrl = dynamic;
    bvnData = BvnData.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(_json['bvn_data'])));
    createdAt = _json['created_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['first_name'] = firstName;
    _data['last_name'] = lastName;
    _data['status'] = status;
    _data['reference'] = reference;
    _data['callback_url'] = callbackUrl;
    _data['bvn_data'] = bvnData.toJson();
    _data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    print(_data);
    return _data;
  }
}

class BvnData {
  BvnData({
     this.nin,
     this.email,
    required this.gender,
    required this.surname,
     this.serialNo,
    required this.faceImage,
    required this.firstName,
     this.landmarks,
     this.branchName,
    required this.middleName,
     this.nameOnCard,
    required this.dateOfBirth,
    required this.lgaOfOrigin,
    required this.watchlisted,
     this.lgaOfCapture,
    required this.phoneNumber1,
    required this.phoneNumber2,
    required this.maritalStatus,
    required this.stateOfOrigin,
     this.enrollBankCode,
    required this.enrollUserName,
     this.enrollmentDate,
    required this.lgaOfResidence,
    required this.stateOfCapture,
     this.additionalInfo1,
    required this.productReference,
    required this.stateOfResidence,
  });
  late final dynamic nin;
  late final dynamic email;
  late final String gender;
  late final String surname;
  late final dynamic serialNo;
  late final String faceImage;
  late final String firstName;
  late final dynamic landmarks;
  late final dynamic branchName;
  late final String middleName;
  late final dynamic nameOnCard;
  late final String dateOfBirth;
  late final String lgaOfOrigin;
  late final String watchlisted;
  late final dynamic lgaOfCapture;
  late final String phoneNumber1;
  late final String phoneNumber2;
  late final String maritalStatus;
  late final String stateOfOrigin;
  late final dynamic enrollBankCode;
  late final String enrollUserName;
  late final dynamic enrollmentDate;
  late final String lgaOfResidence;
  late final String stateOfCapture;
  late final dynamic additionalInfo1;
  late final String productReference;
  late final String stateOfResidence;

  BvnData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    nin = json['nin']?? "none";
    email = json['email']?? "none";
    gender = json['gender']?? "none";
    surname = json['surname']?? "none";
    serialNo = json['serialNo']?? "none";
    faceImage = json['faceImage']?? "none";
    firstName = json['firstName']?? "none";
    landmarks = json['landmarks']?? "none";
    branchName = json['branchName']?? "none";
    middleName = json['middleName']?? "none";
    nameOnCard = json['nameOnCard']?? "none";
    dateOfBirth = json['dateOfBirth']?? "none";
    lgaOfOrigin = json['lgaOfOrigin']?? "none";
    watchlisted = json['watchlisted']?? "none";
    lgaOfCapture = json['lgaOfCapture']?? "none";
    phoneNumber1 = json['phoneNumber1']?? "none";
    phoneNumber2 = json['phoneNumber2']?? "none";
    maritalStatus = json['maritalStatus']?? "none";
    stateOfOrigin = json['stateOfOrigin']?? "none";
    enrollBankCode = json['enrolBankCode']?? "none";
    enrollUserName = json['enrollUserName']?? "none";
    enrollmentDate = json['enrollmentDate']?? "none";
    lgaOfResidence = json['lgaOfResidence']?? "none";
    stateOfCapture = json['stateOfCapture']?? "none";
    additionalInfo1 = json['additionalInfo1']?? "none";
    productReference = json['productReference']?? "none";
    stateOfResidence = json['stateOfResidence']?? "none";
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['nin'] = nin;
    _data['email'] = email;
    _data['gender'] = gender;
    _data['surname'] = surname;
    _data['serialNo'] = serialNo;
    _data['faceImage'] = faceImage;
    _data['firstName'] = firstName;
    _data['landmarks'] = landmarks;
    _data['branchName'] = branchName;
    _data['middleName'] = middleName;
    _data['nameOnCard'] = nameOnCard;
    _data['dateOfBirth'] = dateOfBirth;
    _data['lgaOfOrigin'] = lgaOfOrigin;
    _data['watchlisted'] = watchlisted;
    _data['lgaOfCapture'] = lgaOfCapture;
    _data['phoneNumber1'] = phoneNumber1;
    _data['phoneNumber2'] = phoneNumber2;
    _data['maritalStatus'] = maritalStatus;
    _data['stateOfOrigin'] = stateOfOrigin;
    _data['enrollBankCode'] = enrollBankCode;
    _data['enrollUserName'] = enrollUserName;
    _data['enrollmentDate'] = enrollmentDate;
    _data['lgaOfResidence'] = lgaOfResidence;
    _data['stateOfCapture'] = stateOfCapture;
    _data['additionalInfo1'] = additionalInfo1;
    _data['productReference'] = productReference;
    _data['stateOfResidence'] = stateOfResidence;
    print(_data);
    return _data;
  }
}
```

The data returned is as follows

{
"status": "success",
"message": "Bvn details fetched",
"data": {
"first_name": "LYRA",
"last_name": "Balacqua",
"status": "COMPLETED",
"reference": "FLW441BD872AEBB28BD53B239",
"callback_url": null,
"bvn_data": {
"nin": "485xxxxxx33",
"email": "test-user@example.com",
"gender": "Male",
"surname": "Balacqua",
"serialNo": null,
"faceImage": "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",
"firstName": "LYRA ",
"landmarks": null,
"branchName": null,
"middleName": "USER ",
"nameOnCard": null,
"dateOfBirth": "199x-05-xxT23:00:00Z",
"lgaOfOrigin": "Test lga",
"watchlisted": "0.0",
"lgaOfCapture": null,
"phoneNumber1": "234810xxxx188",
"phoneNumber2": null,
"maritalStatus": "Single",
"stateOfOrigin": "Lagos State",
"enrollBankCode": null,
"enrollUserName": "user@example.com",
"enrollmentDate": null,
"lgaOfResidence": "Ikorodu",
"stateOfCapture": "Lagos State",
"additionalInfo1": null,
"productReference": "FLW441BD872AEBB28BD53B239",
"stateOfResidence": "Lagos State"
},
"created_at": "2023-04-13T23:02:23.000Z"
}
}
How can I fix the issue for the App to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to decode and encode again the map.

Replace the below code

```
 bvnData = BvnData.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(_json['bvn_data'])));
```

with

```
 bvnData = BvnData.fromJson(_json['bvn_data']);
```

Checkout this model

```
    import 'dart:convert';

BvnConsent bvnConsentFromJson(String str) =>
    BvnConsent.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String bvnConsentToJson(BvnConsent data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class BvnConsent {
  String status;
  String message;
  Data data;

  BvnConsent({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.data,
  });

  factory BvnConsent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BvnConsent(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
        "data": data.toJson(),
      };
}

class Data {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String status;
  String reference;
  dynamic callbackUrl;
  BvnData bvnData;
  DateTime createdAt;

  Data({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.status,
    required this.reference,
    required this.callbackUrl,
    required this.bvnData,
    required this.createdAt,
  });

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        firstName: json["first_name"],
        lastName: json["last_name"],
        status: json["status"],
        reference: json["reference"],
        callbackUrl: json["callback_url"],
        bvnData: BvnData.fromJson(json["bvn_data"]),
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "status": status,
        "reference": reference,
        "callback_url": callbackUrl,
        "bvn_data": bvnData.toJson(),
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
      };
}

class BvnData {
  String nin;
  String email;
  String gender;
  String surname;
  dynamic serialNo;
  String faceImage;
  String firstName;
  dynamic landmarks;
  dynamic branchName;
  String middleName;
  dynamic nameOnCard;
  String dateOfBirth;
  String lgaOfOrigin;
  String watchlisted;
  dynamic lgaOfCapture;
  String phoneNumber1;
  dynamic phoneNumber2;
  String maritalStatus;
  String stateOfOrigin;
  dynamic enrollBankCode;
  String enrollUserName;
  dynamic enrollmentDate;
  String lgaOfResidence;
  String stateOfCapture;
  dynamic additionalInfo1;
  String productReference;
  String stateOfResidence;

  BvnData({
    required this.nin,
    required this.email,
    required this.gender,
    required this.surname,
    required this.serialNo,
    required this.faceImage,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.landmarks,
    required this.branchName,
    required this.middleName,
    required this.nameOnCard,
    required this.dateOfBirth,
    required this.lgaOfOrigin,
    required this.watchlisted,
    required this.lgaOfCapture,
    required this.phoneNumber1,
    required this.phoneNumber2,
    required this.maritalStatus,
    required this.stateOfOrigin,
    required this.enrollBankCode,
    required this.enrollUserName,
    required this.enrollmentDate,
    required this.lgaOfResidence,
    required this.stateOfCapture,
    required this.additionalInfo1,
    required this.productReference,
    required this.stateOfResidence,
  });

  factory BvnData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => BvnData(
        nin: json["nin"],
        email: json["email"],
        gender: json["gender"],
        surname: json["surname"],
        serialNo: json["serialNo"],
        faceImage: json["faceImage"],
        firstName: json["firstName"],
        landmarks: json["landmarks"],
        branchName: json["branchName"],
        middleName: json["middleName"],
        nameOnCard: json["nameOnCard"],
        dateOfBirth: json["dateOfBirth"],
        lgaOfOrigin: json["lgaOfOrigin"],
        watchlisted: json["watchlisted"],
        lgaOfCapture: json["lgaOfCapture"],
        phoneNumber1: json["phoneNumber1"],
        phoneNumber2: json["phoneNumber2"],
        maritalStatus: json["maritalStatus"],
        stateOfOrigin: json["stateOfOrigin"],
        enrollBankCode: json["enrollBankCode"],
        enrollUserName: json["enrollUserName"],
        enrollmentDate: json["enrollmentDate"],
        lgaOfResidence: json["lgaOfResidence"],
        stateOfCapture: json["stateOfCapture"],
        additionalInfo1: json["additionalInfo1"],
        productReference: json["productReference"],
        stateOfResidence: json["stateOfResidence"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "nin": nin,
        "email": email,
        "gender": gender,
        "surname": surname,
        "serialNo": serialNo,
        "faceImage": faceImage,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "landmarks": landmarks,
        "branchName": branchName,
        "middleName": middleName,
        "nameOnCard": nameOnCard,
        "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth,
        "lgaOfOrigin": lgaOfOrigin,
        "watchlisted": watchlisted,
        "lgaOfCapture": lgaOfCapture,
        "phoneNumber1": phoneNumber1,
        "phoneNumber2": phoneNumber2,
        "maritalStatus": maritalStatus,
        "stateOfOrigin": stateOfOrigin,
        "enrollBankCode": enrollBankCode,
        "enrollUserName": enrollUserName,
        "enrollmentDate": enrollmentDate,
        "lgaOfResidence": lgaOfResidence,
        "stateOfCapture": stateOfCapture,
        "additionalInfo1": additionalInfo1,
        "productReference": productReference,
        "stateOfResidence": stateOfResidence,
      };
}
```

Comment: I replaced that, but still getting the error - type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Comment: In the IDE whatever you using remove try catch block and check again, this will help you identify the exact location from where this error generating

Comment: Sorry, the initial code blocked I copied out was wrong. I have updated it now. 
The rror is triggered on this line - final response = BvnConsent.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value.data)));

Comment: I updated the answer, checkout the updated model

Comment: after copying the updated model into the application, I still got same error -  Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'. Where else can the issue come from?

Comment: @mogbonjubade-ayoade you're getting json from api. In the controller you're doing  json encoding and decoding that is not useful. You can simply use

 final response = BvnConsent.fromJson(value.data);

Comment: I have reverted to - final response = BvnConsent.fromJson(value.data);
Still getting the error  Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Add breakpoint or debug point to that particular line and check what you're getting in the value.data